# UWP EntityFrameworkCore Migration issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, uwp, entity-framework-core

I'm new to UWP and I'm trying to build my first application with EntityFrameworkCore. My setup is this:

```
Visual Studio 2019
UWP target version - W10 version 1903
UWP min verion - W10 Fall Creators Update

Nuget installed packages:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore - 2.2.6
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design - 2.2.6
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite - 2.2.6
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools - 2.2.6
(3.0.1 the latest versions support only .NETStandard 2.1 so I can't use them in a UWP app)

Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform - 6.2.9
```

I created the model and the DBContext and now I need to create my database, and the only way is to do it through Migrations. Here is where I'm getting issues:

I can't use Nuget Console because Tools do not support UWP.

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate 
Startup project 'Test' is a Universal Windows Platform app. This version of the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support this type of project.
```

I can't use the dotnet-ef because of different errors:

```
$ dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0
$ dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\rev\Test.csproj(219,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v16.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an MSBuild-based .NET Core project. If you're using custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.
```

I'm completely blocked. Is there anything else I can try or should I use something else than Entity Framework?

**UPDATE**

I edited the .csproj and replace the  tag with a different url, from the Visual Studio folder and it seems that it passes this error.

But I'm getting something else:

```
$ dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\rev\obj\Test.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets(4,5): error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "GetEFProjectMetadata". [C:\Users\admin\Desktop\rev\Test.csproj]
Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an MSBuild-based .NET Core project. If you're using custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the error message, if you use dotnet-CLI for database migration management in the UWP project, this is not supported

Currently, UWP projects still use `.Net Standard 2.0` and do not support dotnet-CLI for `Asp.Net Core 3`.

If you want to use dotnet-CLI to manage your database, you can only do it outside of the UWP project.

Best regards.

Comment: I can't use Nuget console on UWP, but I should be able to use dotnet. People are using it...

Comment: Hi, As your test results show, you need to build your database migration on a .net core-based project, such as `.Net Core Console App`, or Web App. The UWP project is based on `.Net Standard 2.0`. Although some .Net Core libraries can be used, UWP are not completely based on .Net Core